# Reducing number of argumnets passed to function

Tags: c++, function

I have a class named `Window`, and a big bunch of functions which need an instance of `Window` to work. So I have passed `Window* win` as an argument to each of these functions, but this approach creates a copy of `Window*` every time it is called and also, it seems kinda unnecessary passing the argument to each function. I have tried passing `const Window*` but that won't work either because the functions inside `Window` don't have a `const` version. I thought that using `std:::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` would help, but I still haven't figured it out correctly. Here's my current code:

```cpp
// Window.h
class Window
{
public:
// some getters/setters and other functions
private:
// members are here
};

// on another file
int func1(Window* win /*I want to remove this */, ...) {
// use win and other parameters
}
```

And here's the smart pointers approach.

```cpp
// class Window as declared above

// file.h
namespace space
{
struct context;

context* make_context(std::shared_ptr<Window> const& win); // const& to avoid copy

void destroy_context(context* ctx);

int func1(...); // note that ... is used to show some params whose type isn't important for the question.
}

// some other functions
```

```cpp
// file.cpp
namespace space
{
struct context
{
std::weak_ptr<Window> target;
};

context* make_context(std::shared_ptr<Window> const& win) // const& to avoid copy
{
context* ctx = new context{};
ctx->target = win;
return ctx;
}

void destroy_context(context* ctx)
{
  if(ctx != nullptr)
  {
    delete ctx;
    ctx = nullptr;
  }
}

int func1(...)
{
// use ... params
} // int func1(...)
} // namespace space
```

```cpp
// main.cpp 

int main(int, char**)
{
  std::shared_ptr<Window> window{new Window{/*some arguments*/}};

  auto ctx{space::make_context(window)};

int func1();
// some other code

  delete ctx;
}
```

Comment: `this approach is expensive because it creates a copy of Window every time it is called` This is incorrect. It creates a copy of a `Window` **pointer** each time one of the functions is called. Copying pointers is about as cheap as it gets.

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` address issues with the cleanup of resources. They have no bearing on your issue.

Comment: also "but that won't work either because the functions inside Window don't have a const version." then you should fixed that methods better sooner than later. Methods that can be `const` but are not declared as `const` create big problems on the long run (like for example sometimes the need to make copies when actually no copy is needed)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @john and @Yksisarvinen. It was a typo of mine. However, do you know any way to avoid passing a `Window*` on each function, as it gets boring, and also, there are a lot of functions that need that `Window*`?

Comment: @TerensTare Put those functions into some kind of class that has a Window pointer as a data member? Whether that's a good idea or not depends on the design of your code.

Comment: From your description it seems that `Window` is a global object, just disguised. If there is no risk of multithreading (e.g. two threads modifying `Window` at the same time), you could just make it truly global and have everyone know that.

Comment: I would do that @Yksisarvinen, but there is the possibility to have more than one `Window*` at a time, that's why I had to pass a `Window*` to each function.

Comment: Then you should probably organize those functions in classes, like john suggested.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Adding the functions on a class with `Window*` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained already in the various comments, a parameter which is a pointer like Window* will never create a copy of the Window object. This is why a pointer is made for.

Before trying to figure out more complex tools like smart pointers, I suggest you first spend time understanding C++ fundamental. You should start by what is a  value, what is a pointer, what is a reference.